# Colorbox modal is blank when opened

Tags: jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am testing a website where I must click on a button that opens up a lightbox, I believe it is Colorbox - a jQuery lightbox. The problem is sometimes, when I click on it,the frame opens up but nothing loads on it. It is just grayed out. I have a dynamic wait that will wait for a certain element to show up with a time out of 100 seconds, but the frame doesn't even load in 100s.

I am wondering if anyone else has run into this problem or has experienced this?

I am running tests in chrome and phantomjs. This error occurs in both.

```
$(By.xpath(".//*[@id='sectionLink']/a")).click();

    // switch to the pop up window
    WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().switchTo().defaultContent();
    WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().switchTo().frame($(By.className("cboxIframe")));


    List<WebElement> elements = WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));

    WebElement iframe;
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
        if ("cboxiframe".equals(elements.get(i).getAttribute("className"))) {
            iframe = elements.get(i);
            WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().switchTo().frame(iframe);
            break;
        }
    }

    WebDriverRunner.getWebDriver().switchTo().activeElement();


    $(".standard").shouldHave(text("Fund name:"));
```

Comment: yes i have experienced this

Comment: have you try waiting a bit before clicking on a button which loads this Jquery dialog.

Comment: please show your code.

Comment: @JackMarchetti Code has been added, I am not sure what the for loop is for... It was written by someone else.

Comment: @divine did you manage to fix/workout this?

Comment: @GaurangShah I will try this, thanks

Comment: @Jay yes i did,

Comment: @divine Care to share how you went about doing this?

Comment: @Jay you have mentioned that you are facing issue in color box related code. but you haven't posted any actual colorbox code that you've created . Post your colorbox implementation

Comment: @divine I didn't code the website, I am just testing it